# NPM and hubspot CMS/ CLI integration

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, hubspot

Installation should be simple, as it is very straightforward. I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious.

1. I have NPM installed

   [image]
2. I try and install using npm install -g @hubspot/cms-cli

   [image]

   I used the global flag in my /usr/local/bin/ directory.
3. Using hs init returns "zsh: command not found: hs"
4. Using npm list it shows empty

   [image]
5. Moving to my project directory, it shows hubspot installed, but nothing underneath it

   [image]
6. I try installing in project directory, same issue. It shows HubSpot installed with nothing underneath it and hs init returns the same "zsh: command not found:hs" message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please try like this

if not, you'll need to follow these steps as a prerequisite

```
1  npm init

2  npm install @hubspot/cms-cli

3  npx hs init
```

Its worked for me :)